# How to split a PostgreSQL table into multi parts?

Tags: postgresql

We're developing a tool to make a snapshot of our PostgreSQL.

To increase the performance, we decide to split the task into multi subtasks.

e.g. A table has 100 million records, split it into 100 parts, and each part has 1 million records.

We tried using the primary key to split the table, however, most of our table's primary key is not a uniform distribution, simple math can't work. Then we use the following SQL to generate the pk-ranges:

```
select {pk} from {table} where pk >= {prev-range-upper} order by {prev-range-upper} limit 1 offset {part-size}
```

Sometimes it works well when the plan using `Index only scan`, however, in other times, maybe when the `{part-size}` is bigger than the size of the filtered dataset, it uses `Seq scan` instead, even when Seq Scan disabled, it uses `bitmap index scan`.

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=507124.19..507124.19 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Sort  (cost=505205.36..507124.19 rows=767532 width=8)
        Sort Key: product_id
        ->  Seq Scan on tbl_product  (cost=0.00..419683.11 rows=767532 width=8)
              Filter: (product_id >= 1492803875)

QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=512501.56..512501.56 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Sort  (cost=510578.83..512501.56 rows=769090 width=8)
        Sort Key: product_id
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_product  (cost=14400.87..424872.05 rows=769090 width=8)
              Recheck Cond: (product_id >= 1492803875)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tbl_product_pkey  (cost=0.00..14208.60 rows=769090 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (product_id >= 1492803875)
```

We don't need each part to have exactly the same size. Being almost the same is acceptable.

Maybe we're on the wrong way, any alternative is welcome.
This question is about PostgreSQL, the general solution works for both PostgreSQL and MySQL is better;
But we do not decide to use ETL tools like `sqoop`, `dataX`, etc. now.

#edit
`set random_page_cost = 1` makes PostgreSQL generate the better plan..

Comment: This sounds like [table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html). What do you mean by a tool to take a snapshot? Like [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html)?

Comment: @Schwern, we develop the tool to extract our data from PostgreSQL to Hive. there's some additional logic in it like sharding merge, data desensitization to develop a lightweight tool instead to integrate(even modify) an external tool to do it.

Comment: I would just extract the total number of records and use one single sequential scan that would feed the n subtasks by simply counting the records. IMHO if you want to process the whole table, it will certainly be the most efficient way.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm not sure I understand you, do you mean just `select * from {table}` in on thread has better performance than run several subtasks like `select * from {table} where {subtask_filter}` concurrently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ntile()` to get your cutoffs:

```
# \d exntile;
                            Table "public.exntile"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |               Default
--------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------
 id     | bigint  |           | not null | nextval('exntile_id_seq'::regclass)
 value  | integer |           |          |
Indexes:
    "exntile_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

# with tiles as (
  select ntile(15) over (order by id) as p, id 
    from exntile
)
select p, min(id), max(id)
  from tiles
 group by p
 order by p;
 p  | min  |  max  
----+------+-------
  1 |    1 |   667
  2 |  668 |  1334
  3 | 1335 |  2001
  4 | 2002 |  2668
  5 | 2669 |  3335
  6 | 3336 |  4002
  7 | 4003 |  4669
  8 | 4670 |  5336
  9 | 5337 |  6003
 10 | 6004 |  6670
 11 | 6671 |  7337
 12 | 7338 |  8003
 13 | 8004 |  8669
 14 | 8670 |  9335
 15 | 9336 | 10001
(15 rows)
```

I ran this to delete some rows a few times:

```
delete from exntile 
 where id in (select floor(random() * 100001 + 1)::int 
                from generate_series(1, 2500));
```

And it still balances:

```
with tiles as (                                                                                          
  select ntile(15) over (order by id) as p, id 
    from exntile
)
select p, min(id), max(id), count(*)
  from tiles
 group by p
 order by p;

 p  | min  |  max  | count 
----+------+-------+-------
  1 |    2 |   657 |   555
  2 |  658 |  1337 |   555
  3 | 1338 |  2017 |   555
  4 | 2018 |  2670 |   555
  5 | 2671 |  3351 |   555
  6 | 3352 |  4016 |   555
  7 | 4017 |  4680 |   555
  8 | 4681 |  5345 |   555
  9 | 5346 |  6011 |   555
 10 | 6012 |  6685 |   555
 11 | 6686 |  7355 |   555
 12 | 7356 |  8044 |   555
 13 | 8045 |  8690 |   555
 14 | 8691 |  9353 |   555
 15 | 9354 | 10001 |   555
(15 rows)
```

```
explain analyze with tiles as (
  select ntile(15) over (order by id) as p, id 
    from exntile
)
select p, min(id), max(id), count(*)
  from tiles
 group by p
 order by p;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=701.17..701.67 rows=200 width=28) (actual time=25.503..25.506 rows=15 loops=1)
   Sort Key: tiles.p
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
   CTE tiles
     ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.29..434.91 rows=8554 width=12) (actual time=7.936..12.347 rows=8325 loops=1)
           ->  Index Only Scan using exntile_pkey on exntile  (cost=0.29..306.60 rows=8554 width=8) (actual time=0.056..5.546 rows=8325 loops=1)
                 Heap Fetches: 8325
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=256.62..258.62 rows=200 width=28) (actual time=25.464..25.475 rows=15 loops=1)
         Group Key: tiles.p
         ->  CTE Scan on tiles  (cost=0.00..171.08 rows=8554 width=12) (actual time=7.941..18.481 rows=8325 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.226 ms
 Execution time: 25.800 ms
(12 rows)
```

Comment: Works nicely except for its performance, do you know any way faster? Better or just `Index only scan` level performance is good, and we can accept each part *NOT* to be exactly the same size.

Comment: @a.l.  Added my query plan.  I'm getting an `Index Only Scan`.  If you are not, then maybe try rewriting the CTE as a subquery or making sure your table stats are up to date?

Comment: After explicitly set `set enable_seqscan = OFF;` it become `Index Only Scan`.

Comment: I guess the index statistics contain enough information for our requirement，do you know how to query that?

Comment: @a.l. Are you asking how to update statistics?  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Introduction_to_VACUUM,_ANALYZE,_EXPLAIN,_and_COUNT#Using_ANALYZE_to_optimize_PostgreSQL_queries

Comment: And exactly our tables are not the same size,  so we don't know how to specify the `num` for `ntile`  function before we run `count(*)` query which need to scan the index one time. Any `ntile` variant that uses `size of each part` as argument?

Comment: No, I think there's a faster way to archive this, instead of `Index Only Scan`, it just uses the statistics...Forgot it if it makes you confused... After all, thanks, Mike.

Comment: @a.l.Understand what you are asking, and it can be done with `row_number()`, but your last chunk will vary wildly in size.  From experience, I would expect that running the exports will far outweigh setting up the runs with these kinds of queries in terms of cost.